# Message isn't delivered when I try to DM my bot in discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a bot in discordpy. I have a discord server for only people in school. Everyone has a school email, and I want to make a bot that can send a code to verify them.

Where I am stuck is that when the bot askes for an email, it wont let me DM the bot back. In discord I'm being told that my message can't be delivered, because we don't share any mutual servers, etc. There are no errors in the python log. Also, when a new person joins, they are banned right away so they can't read or write anything. All of the verification is happening in DM's. The person is only unbanned after they've been verified.

I have tried googling everywhere, but I just cannot find an answer. If there is one that already exists, could you please point me to it?

Is there a solution to this? Or should I try something else, like blocking the user from reading all channels except one?

Thank you so much for your help! It really means a lot to me. ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did for my school server is to have all the channels be locked, then send a verification DM. They can't see the students and they don't have permission to make a new invite, so the user *has* to complete the verification. After that, send the replies to a mod-only channel for approval.

If they have their DMs closed then... That's on them.

Comment: Thank you. I’ve gone with something similar. When they join, they can’t see any channels or members. A new channel is created for them, where email verification happens by bot, then the channel is closed and they get their permissions back

Comment: My goal is to eliminate the need to ever have a human moderator. Might be a bit hard though 

Answer (score 0):

It's simply something that you aren't allow to do in Discord. It doesn't depend on the Discord API.

> Or should I block the user to see al the channels except one?

this can be the best alternative.